# pdftotext command not working with multiple file

Tags: command-line

RHEL 5.9. I have many pdf files containing tax details. I often use pdftotext -layout command to convert them for further text process. Now issue is that when I use command pdftotext -layout *.pdf its giving error and display usage and option, say man page. Whether it is possible to convert all pdf file to text file with single command.

Comment: No it didn't work and showing error syntax error near pdftotext..

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.pdf; do
    pdftotext -layout "$file"
done
```